# Float one image over another with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I am using bootstrap with some simple code.
Inside the jumbotron div/container i have 2 images. One aligned left. One aligned right.
How do i allow the right image to float over/above the left one on resize of the browser window? Driving me crazy.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">

<div class="left-image">
<img src="left-image.png">
</div>

<div class="right-image">
<img src="right-image.png">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I thought simple css like this would do it?

```
.left-image {
float: left;
}
.right-image {
float: right;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements. And you will need to position your right image `absolute` for this to work, otherwise one image will just push the other further down the page when they start to collide.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u3vxxnoe/2/ see this. is this what you want?

Comment: with absolute positioning, the left/right margins adhere to the browser window and not my container DIV. any way to make the left and right start at zero relative to the container DIV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `position: absolute` if you want your images to overlap

```
.left-image{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
.right-image{
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Edit the left and right properties above to get the positioning to your liking.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4n1s8t9g/)

Comment: with absolute positioning, the left/right margins adhere to the browser window and not my container DIV. any way to make the left and right start at zero relative to the container DIV?

Comment: @lowercase Yes, add `position: relative` to the parent DIV of `.left-image` / `.right-image` that you want to use as the container

Answer (score 2):

I think setting a negative margin right on the left floating element with the amount you want the floating right image to be allowed to overlap.
Example...

```
.left-image {
float: left;
margin-right: -200px;
}
```

I can't test it right now but I think that should work.